# Debian Redirect Single Port of Outbound Connection

Tags: debian, iptables, nat

I have a Debian 11 VM on a Windows machine. It has 3 network adapters. One is external (WAN), one internal (LAN) and another private (experimental).

I am using the box as a router which in turn uses my DSL router back through via the WAN NIC which is actually connected to the Hyper-V box. Everything works routing-wise.

What I'm trying to achieve, and having read many articles have failed this far, is I am trying to intercept a single port (4444) for example, to a single public internet IP address, and reroute that back to a machine on my LAN.  Sounds simple, and I'm sure it is but I can't get it working.

To be clear, this is **NOT** trying to expose a public port and get it routed internally. This is to intercept one single port (the application in question connects to multiple ports).  I want all communication to go to the target server normally, but I want this port directed to my machine where I have a socket server configured to deal with communication.

I know the answer involves iptables but I just can't get the commands right. Whenever I do

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.111:4444`

it doesn't even show up in my `iptables -L`. Forwarding is enabled. I have also tried:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth1 --dport 4444 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.111:4444`

I even applied it to eth0 which is the default gateway.

eth0 - Public WAN

eth1 - LAN

eth2 - Experimenting with assigning the public IP in question but this screws routing for all ports so gave up on that

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I fixed it. It appears if you leave our the `-d <destination address>` from your prerouting it will get ignored.

I also added a SNAT rule to make it appear the packets being returned were from the public IP.

Job done. Hope this helps someone one day.